# Cost of SortedDictionary.Count

Tags: c#

What is the cost of `SortedDictionary.Count` in c#?
Does it retrieve some integer, or does it iterate over the tree?

Answer (score 5):

It simply returns a value from a field, so the cost should be neglectible.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecc800k7.aspx)

> Getting the value of this property is an O(1) operation.

Answer (score 2):

O(1), because it's just a field access.